# Inheriting django.contrib.auth.models leads to not hashing passwords

Tags: python, django

So I am learning how to use Django, and I am currently trying to integrate my `Person` class with Django's `User` class located in package django.contrib.auth.models.  I inherit the class like this:

```
class Person(User):

    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'F'

    GENDER = (
        (MALE, 'Male'),
        (FEMALE, 'Female'),
    )

    birth_date = models.DateField()

    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = GENDER)
```

My form is then defined like this:

```
class SignupForm(ModelForm):
    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'F'

    GENDER = (
        (MALE, 'Male'),
        (FEMALE, 'Female'),
    )

    thisYear = date.today().year

    YEARS = [thisYear - year for year in range(100)]

    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(), min_length=5, max_length = 128)

    birth_date = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years = YEARS), initial='1990-01-01')

    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices = GENDER, initial='M')

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('last_name', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'last_login', 'date_joined', 'user_permissions', 'groups', 'attraction' )

        #all fields in this list will map to a specific model attribute and will be comitted to the database
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'first_name', 'email', 'gender', 'birth_date')
```

I excluded a few things, but you get the point.  In my view, when I create a new `Person`, I call  `newPerson = signupForm.save(commit=False)`.

After adding a few more values to newPerson, I call `newPerson.save()`.

This action creates a new row in two different tables: the `auth_user` table, and the `person` table.

If I query the `auth_user` table, I see that my password was never hashed.  Looking at the Django source, this suggests that `create_user` was never called.  Can someone explain to me how this works?

Also, if anyone can explain how I query the `auth_user` information with a person instance, that would be great, too. There is no explicit foreign key between them, but that inheritance must account for something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are customizing the Django auth_user module

you should create your model like

class Person(models.Model):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User) 
blah = 
.
.
```

don't forget to import User from auth.models

in your views

```
if form.is_valid():
    user = User.objects.create_user(username = form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                    email = form.cleaned_data['email'],
                                    password = form.cleaned_data['password'],
                                    )
```

as django docs said `create_user` will itself hash the password field for you in your auth_user table

you need to change your signUp form also

hope this will help you

Go through http://www.hackedexistence.com/project-django.html  this link